# Is there a website that can tell me which resorts have fresh snow and below freezing weather?

Tags: online-resources, skiing, north-america

Optimal ski days occur when:

1. There's a non-trivial amount of fresh snow/"pow" in the past 24 hours
2. The temperature doesn't increase past the melting point, as otherwise you get icy skiing or "slush" skiing

Is there a website that could quickly show me every single resort in a given area that satisfies both conditions? Plenty of websites will show you snow reports but none that I could find would let you exclude resorts where the temperatures are too high. I only need it to work for US/Canada resorts but don't mind if it works worldwide.

Comment: You might get more focused responses on [The Great Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2):

I am surprised to say that the answer is Yes.  [This](https://www.skiresort.info/weather/usa/) site shows the weather of all ski resorts (the link is set to weather of the resorts in the US, but you can select Canada).  It shows the forecast for the next 7 days.  Note that there are 520+ resorts in the US, so there will be a bit of scrolling involved.

Actually I just noticed that it covered 6100+ resorts world wide.

> Skiresort.info ...
>
> - is the only portal offering information concerning all 6100 ski    resorts worldwide.
> - is the world’s largest ski resort test portal with more than 450 test    reports.
> - uploads 900 snow reports and presents them on a daily basis.
> - presents weather reports from over 5000 ski resorts.
> - uploads more than 5000 webcams and livestreams on a daily basis.
> - displays all new lifts and cable cars for the current season.

Sample of the US forecasts

[image]

---

<sup>I found this by a simple google of "ski resorts in the US"</sup>

Comment: Is there a way to filter the resorts down to just those that meet my criteria? Manually clicking on all the resorts is a bit of a pain :-)

Comment: @JonathanReez From scrolling you can see when snow is forecast, so that tells you when there will be potential fresh powder.  So you only have to click on the resorts where there will be fresh snow in order to verify the temperature details.